# laravel Eloquent ORM custom field name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get record from a products table with the field `productsid` by using Eloquent and using the following code. My model name is Products_description.

In my route file.

```
Route::get('product/{productsid}','productscontroller@show');
```

In my controller file

```
public function show($productid)
{
$Products = Products_description::find($productid);
return $Products;   
}
```

But it showing me the error that `Unknown column 'products_description.id'`. Looks like Eloquent try to get record through the field name `id` by default like it do with the table names. But how to get records through a table field other than `id`. e.g. if it is `productid`, what we would do/use?

Comment: Could you show me table structure and  `Products_description` model class?

Comment: table name is 'products_description' fields are 'productsid' int(11), 'product_name' varchar(64). class Products_description extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'products_description';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, declare your `$primaryKey`

```
class Products_description {
    protected $primaryKey = "productid";

    //
}
```

This way you can use `::find` or `firstOrFail` and not `where`.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
 $Products = Products_description::where('pruductid',$productid)->first();
```

or you can try this

**Products_description model**

```
  class Products_description extends Eloquent {

protected $primaryKey = 'productid';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your need is to query your table for a field other than the primary key . You can use:

```
Products_description::where('productid',$productId)->first()
```

If you are speaking about foreign keys, then you should define them in the model like so :

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');
```

Here is the relevant documentation :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one